# RoR: first_or_initialize block doesn't save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

I have the following code, which works fine with no errors but the models never get saved...

```
myarray.each do |item|

    r = MyModel.unscoped.where(:site_id => @site.id, :url => item['permalink_url']).first_or_initialize do |r|
        r.title              = 'asdasdadaddjfgnfd'
        r.save!
    end
end
```

Terminal shows the SQL SELECT statements when attempting to find the Models, but the UPDATE/INSERT statements never run.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 8):

Rails `first_or_*` methods invoke passed block only for `initialize` or `create` part. If the record is found, the methods just return it so passed block will never run. [Check the source](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_initialize)

So you can use block in `first_or_*` methods only to initialize new items, not to update existing ones. Most likely, records with such conditions exist and don't get updated.

Try to move update code, something like

```
myarray.each do |item|

  r = MyModel.unscoped.where(:site_id => @site.id, :url => item['permalink_url']).first_or_initialize
  r.title              = 'asdasdadaddjfgnfd'
  r.save!

end
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using `.tap()` so i could use my existing block structure but this is also a valid answer

Answer (score 6):

I solved this by using:

`.first_or_initialize.tap() do |r|`

But the comments below are also relevant

Comment: Just what i was looking for for my seeds!

Comment: @laffuste You don't need to use `tap()`. `find_or_initialize` already returns the object.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [`first_or_create`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create). `first_or_initialize` just initializes the object (possibly to prep for saving, but it doesn't have to be).

You're existing code would likely work as follows:

```
r = MyModel.unscoped.where(:site_id => @site.id, :url => item['permalink_url']).first_or_initialize do |r|
    r.title              = 'asdasdadaddjfgnfd'
end

r.save!
```

Comment: Thanks but this will use 1 more sql query than necessary, `first_or_initialize` is better for my purposes